# Ringtone painfully loud compared to music in earbuds

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones

Device: iPhone SE (iOS 16.6.1)

I am listening to music at a low volume on bluetooth earbuds when I get a phone call.

The phone ringer sound is loud enough to cause physical pain and ringing in my ears, even though I have the "ringtone and alert volume" set to zero in Sounds & Haptics.

I used to have an Android phone and there were separate volume settings for phone alerts and music. Is this possible on iOS?

Alternatively, is there a way to prevent the phone ringtone from coming through bluetooth at all?